# How do I consume Api for C# project

Tags: c#, json, api, http

I am trying to consume an Api for c# project.
I have the request body sample as follows:

```
{
   "tx_ref":"hooli-tx-1920bbtytty",
   "amount":"100",
   "currency":"NGN",
   "redirect_url":"https://webhook.site/9d0b00ba-9a69-44fa-a43d-a82c33c36fdc",
   "payment_options":"card",
   "meta":{
      "consumer_id":23,
      "consumer_mac":"92a3-912ba-1192a"
   },
   "customer":{
      "email":"user@gmail.com",
      "phonenumber":"080****4528",
      "name":"Yemi Desola"
   },
   "customizations":{
      "title":"Pied Piper Payments",
      "description":"Middleout isn't free. Pay the price",
      "logo":"https://assets.piedpiper.com/logo.png"
   }
}
```

I want to convert the code to C#, I did it as below, but the "meta", "customer", "customizations" are nested in the request, when I tried to reproduce the nested part of the code to c# I get an error.

Please how do I place my C# code to reflect the body with the nested part of the code?

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {

                                { "tx_ref", "N-872653uy09-9"},
                                { "amount", "500"},
                                { "currency","NGN"},
                                { "redirect_url","mysite.com/ConcludeFunding.aspx"},
                                { "payment_options","card"},
                                { "meta"," "},
                                { "customer"("email",EmailV)  },
                                { "customizations","mysite.com/Assets/Logo.jpg"},

                            };
            //serialization using Newtonsoft JSON 
            string JsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues);
```

Comment: Create classes for your data. You can use a tool like this to automatically generate C# classes based on your JSON: https://json2csharp.com (it's a good idea to use the "Use Pascal Case" option for consistency in property naming)

Comment: If you want to use a Dictionary, it needs to be `<string, Object>` type. Then you create `new Dictionary<string, Object>` objects for the values of the nested datas

Comment: Or use Visual Studio Paste Json As Classes: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please can you show example on how to create new Dictionary<string, Object> objects for the values of the nested datas

Comment: You've already done one level of an object; what is difficult of adding a few more? For example, `{ "meta", new Dictionary<string, Object> {"consumer_id", 23}},`

Answer (score 1):

For this type of situation, I would create a root class. Then I would assign value to the class object and finally I would serialize the object using Newtonsoft JSON.

### Code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace Solve
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class Meta
        {
            public int consumer_id { get; set; }
            public string consumer_mac { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phonenumber { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customizations
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string logo { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public string tx_ref { get; set; }
            public string amount { get; set; }
            public string currency { get; set; }
            public string redirect_url { get; set; }
            public string payment_options { get; set; }
            public Meta meta { get; set; }
            public Customer customer { get; set; }
            public Customizations customizations { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rootObj = new Root()
            {
                tx_ref = "N-872653uy09-9",
                amount = "500",
                currency = "NGN",
                redirect_url = "mysite.com/ConcludeFunding.aspx",
                payment_options = "card",
                meta = new Meta()
                {
                    consumer_id = 23,
                    consumer_mac = "92a3-912ba-1192a"
                },
                customizations = new Customizations()
                {
                    title = "Pied Piper Payments",
                    description = "Middleout isn't free. Pay the price",
                    logo = "https://assets.piedpiper.com/logo.png"
                },
                customer = new Customer()
                {
                    email = "user@gmail.com",
                    phonenumber = "080****4528",
                    name = "Yemi Desola"
                }
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObj);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }
}
```